# Social Follow link-clicks showing up doubled

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting

I'm running some tests on an email in Marketing Cloud. If I click the FB social follow link, it reports that I've clicked it twice.

Any help on this please?

Comment: does you ESP use security software to click links to verify they are not phishing attempts?

Comment: I'm not sure, we're using Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: I'm referring to you email service provider, aka who hosts  your email. are you sure its registering two clicks when you click it. So if you click it again does it register 4 clicks or just three?

Comment: Sorry yes, I'm using Outlook 365. I did what you suggested, clicked twice and it registered 4.